# printing spiral matrix in python

Tags: python

Get stuck at inner square of printing spiral matrix pattern in Python

**Code**

```
num=int(input("enter numbers:")) # taking value num=4
arr=[[0 for x in range(num)] for y in range(num)]
n=1
low=0
high=num-1
c=1
# c=int((num+1)/2)
for i in range(c):
    for j in range(low,high+1): #left to right
        arr[i][j]=n
        n=n+1
    for j in range(low+1,high+1):# top to bootom
        arr[j][high]=n
        n=n+1
    for j in range(high-1,low-1,-1): # right to left
        arr[high][j]=n
        n=n+1
    for j in range(high-1,low,-1): # down to up
        arr[j][low]=n
        n=n+1
    for j in range(low+1,high): # inner left to right
        arr[low+1][j]=n
        n=n+1
    # for j in range(1,high):
    #     arr[j][high]=n
    #     n=n+1
    # for j in range(1):
    #     arr[low+1][j]=n
    #     n=n+1

for i in range(num):
    for j in range(num):
        print(arr[i][j],end="\t")
    print()
```

**Expected output**

1       2       3       4

12      13      14      5

11       16       15      6

10       9        8       7

**My output**

1       2       3       4

12      13      14      5

11       0        0       6

10       9        8       7

Comment: What is your question? Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these results with expected results. Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. Then ask a _specific_ question if you are still confused by your code's behavior. It's not okay to dump your code and expect other people to debug it for you

Answer (score 0):

I adapted your program. It has a very good reasonning, the only problem is that you manually wrtite the loops. Instead, as the four fist loops wrote the numbers drawing squares, I just wrote a program that aplies those loops many times.

```py
num=int(input("enter numbers:")) # taking value num=4
arr=[[0 for x in range(num)] for y in range(num)]
n=1
# c=int((num+1)/2)

def square(low,high,array):
    global n
    for j in range(low,high+1): #left to right
        array[i][j]=n
        n=n+1
    for j in range(low+1,high+1):# top to bootom
        array[j][high]=n
        n=n+1
    for j in range(high-1,low-1,-1): # right to left
        array[high][j]=n
        n=n+1
    for j in range(high-1,low,-1): # down to up
        array[j][low]=n
        n=n+1

if num%2==0:
  rg=num//2
else:
  rg=(num+1)//2
for i in range(rg):
    square(i,num-1-i,arr)
```

The rg is just so odd numbers execute the right amount of times.